# CSS3 Conveyor belt effect

Tags: css

say I have this:

```
<ul id="belt">
    <li class="plate">First item here</li>
    <li class="plate">Second item here</li>
    <li class="plate">Third item here</li>
    <li class="plate">Fourth item here</li>
</ul>
```

How can I use CSS3 to make a smooth scrolling conveyor belt like effect, where the list scrolls upwards, and the last item is followed by the first item on the list, like a ring...?

Comment: i think you will need some javascript too, because you have to add/move the first element to the bottom of the list if you scroll it up

Comment: For a nice JS-based solution you can check out [JQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Not in pure css (3 or otherwise).

You could do it in javascript though.

Comment: I dunno... If you added a couple redundant items, I think you could probably get the effect done with nested div's and CSS animations. (unfortunately not semantic, but oh well, it'd get it done)

Comment: @Abhishek I'd suggest you to do this with BOTH javascript and CSS3, using CSS3 to animate and JS to reorder elements. Using pure Javascript for animations is so 90s.

Comment: @Zanfa - Lol... So 90's indeed!

Comment: @Abhishek Actually, look into using jQuery or some other framework that supports falling back to a pure JS solution if CSS3 is not supported. CSS3 is hardware supported (or will be very soon) in most browsers, even on mobile Safari (when using 3D transforms), but older browsers could run the process inefficiently in Javscript and everybody would be happy.

Comment: @Zanfa - Hahaha... Yeah, true... I would prefer a greater reliance on CSS3, to do a bulk of the animation and what not using 3d transforms, and just have JS (either vanilla or flavored) to change the transform values...