# JavaScript infinite up and down element scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to make use of JavaScript (probably jQuery too?) in order to make the contents of a fixed-height div element scroll infinitely up and down (top, bottom, top, bottom, etc) when the page loads and *without* any user input or manipulation?

Thanks ahead of time, any input is greatly appreciated as I am hardly mediocre with JavaScript.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826464/css3-conveyor-belt-effect and here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Comment: If you found your own answer, please put it in the answers section and mark it as the correct answer. Don't just edit the question with the answer you found.

Comment: I would have but I don't have a reputation of 100 and it hasn't been 8 hours yet.. I figured it would be better to make an edit and say I found the answer rather than letting people waste their time attempting to answer it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure js you can do something like this:

```
var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
var delta = 15;
var lastSc;

    //console.log(scroller.scrollTop, scrollHeight);
setInterval(function(){
    var sc = scroller.scrollTop + delta;
    scroller.scrollTop = sc;
    if (scroller.scrollTop === lastSc){
        delta = delta*(-1);
    }
    lastSc = scroller.scrollTop;
}, 10);
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/5n83Z/2/)

Edit: updated demo

Comment: The `scrollHeight` gives value bigger than the real contents height. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5n83Z/1/) it scrolls beyond the actual contents.

Comment: Though that would also work for my liking, I actually found a suitable solution right before you made that post. Thanks though, I'll definitely bookmark that one for future use. :)

Comment: @Shadow, because content height was intentionaly set to 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I've just written, using jQuery:

```
var speed = 100; //smaller means faster
var offset = 5; //bigger means more text will be "scrolled" every time

function ScrollMyDiv() {
    var myDiv = $("#MyDiv");
    var direction = myDiv.attr("scroll_dir") || "";
    var lastScrollTop = parseInt(myDiv.attr("last_scroll_top") || "0", 10);
    if (direction.length === 0) {
        myDiv.attr("scroll_dir", "down");
        direction = "down";
    }
    var top = myDiv.scrollTop();
    myDiv.attr("last_scroll_top", top + "")
    if (direction === "down") {
        if (top > 0 && lastScrollTop === top)
            myDiv.attr("scroll_dir", "up");
        top += offset;
    } else {
        if (top <= 0)
            myDiv.attr("scroll_dir", "down");
        top -= offset;
    }

    myDiv.scrollTop(top);
    window.setTimeout(ScrollMyDiv, speed);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ScrollMyDiv();
});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/HmfNJ/1/

Basically, it will start by scrolling down (adding to the `scrollTop`) then when it identify it reached the bottom by seeing the `scrollTop` remains the same, it will change direction and start scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but I found my answer elsewhere. Here's what I ended up using: http://jsbin.com/onohan/3/edit#preview

It had a couple of small problems but I at least knew enough about basic JavaScript to fix them. Hopefully this will benefit someone in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a smooth transition for scroll to bottom this is VanillaJS code that works well with me

```
var delta = 0.6, interval;
interval = setInterval(function(){
    window.scrollBy(0, delta);
}, 20);
```

To clear the Interval you can run

```
clearInterval(interval);
```